# laravel-echo-server 404 when trying to authenticate

Tags: php, laravel, socket.io, echo

I'm setting up a laravel-echo-server, when I try to authenticate to a private channel, I get the error: Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 404.

Authorizing public channels works.

//channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('private-test', function($user) {
return true;
});
```

//front-end script to authenticate to private channel

```
window.Echo.private('private-test')
.listen('TestMessage', (e) => {
    app.updateChat(e);
});
```

//laravel-echo-server.json

```
{
"authHost": "basic.test",
"authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
"clients": [],
"database": "redis",
"databaseConfig": {
    "redis": {},
    "sqlite": {
        "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
    }
},
"devMode": false,
"host": null,
"port": "6001",
"protocol": "http",
"socketio": {},
"sslCertPath": "",
"sslKeyPath": "",
"sslCertChainPath": "",
"sslPassphrase": "",
"apiOriginAllow": {
    "allowCors": false,
    "allowOrigin": "",
    "allowMethods": "",
    "allowHeaders": ""
    }
}
```

//bootstrap.js

```
window._ = require('lodash');

/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap-sass');
} catch (e) {}

/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = window.Laravel.csrfToken;
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Next we will register the CSRF Token as a common header with Axios so that
 * all outgoing HTTP requests automatically have it attached. This is just
 * a simple convenience so we don't have to attach every token manually.
 */

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}

/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

 import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

 // window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

 // window.Echo = new Echo({
 //     broadcaster: 'pusher',
 //     key: 'your-pusher-key'
 // });

 window.Echo = new Echo({
     broadcaster: 'socket.io',
     host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
 });
```

Simply, my laravel echo gets loaded in from a app.js in public/js, all the libraries within bootstrap.js get loaded in. AFAIK, there is no issue in loading in the right javascript or front-end syntax.

I can add public channels and send messages over them, however I cannot authenticate to private channels.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After the longest time, (I've been trying to fix this issue for ages), I found what I missed.

In config/app.php

```
App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
```

has to be uncommented (obviously).